# Erratic behaiour of PR2 in simulation

Tags: ros, pr2-controllers, pr2-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a simulated PR2 in ROS Indigo (Ubuntu 14.04). While running

roslaunch  pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch

the head of PR2 turns back and the arms get twisted and rotates continously. Also it is not possible to control the simulated PR2 using keyboad teleop package. It was working fine untill all the ros-indigo packages  were updated through synaptic package manager .

It happens when the pr2_default_controllers are up and running. Simulation with no controllers makes no issues.

[arms colliding and looking back http://s17.postimg.org/vbi9cyqqm/Screenshot_from_2015_05_22_15_20_25.jpg](http://s17.postimg.org/vbi9cyqqm/Screenshot_from_2015_05_22_15_20_25.jpg)
[arms rotating http://s22.postimg.org/hd1uy0rio/Screenshot_from_2015_05_22_15_21_04.jpg](http://s22.postimg.org/hd1uy0rio/Screenshot_from_2015_05_22_15_21_04.jpg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209733/erratic-behaiour-of-pr2-in-simulation/) by [achuwilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/1658/achuwilson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2015-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but this could be caused by [ros-controls/control_toolbox/issues/40](https://github.com/ros-controls/control_toolbox/issues/40).

See also [Critical bugfix: Avoid control_toolbox 1.13.1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ros-sig-robot-control/rIrmgRaLcD0/L5Of4A7A07gJ) on `ros-sig-robot-control`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achuwilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/1658/achuwilson/) on 2015-05-23**:
Thank You. It was exactly the issue. Upgrading to 1.13.2 version of control toolbox solved the problem.